# ToolTip flicker in Java if outside JFrame?

Tags: java, swing

I am implementing ToolTip in Java as to make users having an easier time to use the product. Though tooltip that are at the borders of the JFrame and ends up outside the JFrame starts to "flicker". I've tried lots of things (like moving the tooltip so it should be inside the Jframe, controlling the painting so it ends up within the JFrame and so on) though it doesn't work.

Anyone got any expertise within the field that know how to avoid this problem?

Cheers,
Skarion

Comment: You should ask this question on StackOverflow.com

Comment: What content is in the JFrame? It might be that it needs some form of double buffering.

Comment: Just a simple JPanel (with quite a lot of sub-panels as well), so that shouldn't be a issue?

Comment: An SSCCE would be very helpful.

Comment: Well, I'm toying with 30 classes so an SSCCE would be problematic, and as it's flickering it's hard to get a picture of it. Basis seems to be that any tooltip that is too close to JFrame limit seems to quickly flicker and then disapear.

Comment: You made a statement that a tooltip too close to the JFrame limit seems to flicker. So prove your thought by creating a JFrame with a single component and see if you still have the same behavour. If you do then post the SSCCE. If not, then you need to investigate further to see what is different about your real application. This is part of problem solving, you need to isolate the problem. Once you do that we can hopefully suggest a solution.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the effect with this sscce: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorialJWS/uiswing/components/ex6/ButtonDemo.jnlp

Comment: private Timer t = new Timer(40,this);
 private JPanel m;
 
 public Test(){
  m = new JPanel();
  Dimension d = new Dimension(30,30);
  m.setPreferredSize(d);
  m.setSize(d);
  m.setToolTipText("ssAASASASASAsdsdsdsds");
  JPanel main = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
  main.add(m, BorderLayout.EAST);
  ScWindow s = new ScWindow("Test",120,120);
  s.show(main);
  GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
  GraphicsDevice gs = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
  gs.setFullScreenWindow(s);
  t.start(); 
 }

Comment: //The second part on when I create a similar approach.
 public static void main(String[] e){
  Test v = new Test();
 }
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
  m.updateUI();
 }
 private class ScWindow extends JFrame{
  public ScWindow(String title, int xSize, int ySize){
   setTitle(title);
   setSize(xSize, ySize);
   setPreferredSize(new Dimension(xSize, ySize));
   setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }
  public void request(){
   requestFocusInWindow();
  }
  
  public void show(JPanel main){
   setContentPane(main);
   pack();
   setVisible(true);
  }
 }

Answer (score 1):

When a tooltip is displayed in a JFrame, Swing does not create a floating window, it simply paints the tooltip in the graphic context of the JFrame. This does not generate any flickering.
On the other hand, when a tooltip is outside the boundaries of the JFrame, it becomes heavyweight: a window is created to host the tooltip component. Flickering occurs when the tooltip window appears.

Maybe setting "-Dsun.awt.noerasebackground=true" would help because it prevents one step of background repainting of the hosting window.