# Possible to stop flickering java tooltip in heavyweight mode?

Tags: java, tooltip, flicker

Similar Q to [ToolTip flicker in Java if outside JFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922182/tooltip-flicker-in-java-if-outside-jframe)

A constantly updating lightweight tooltip works fine, but once it moves out the window bounds or is made heavyweight (by disabling lightweight popups), it's flicker city.

Tried the "-Dsun.awt.noerasebackground=true" hint which works inside a window, but at the expense of some painting artefacts over other components (this example is just a blank panel). Outside a window bounds it doesn't help, there's still horrible amounts of flicker.

Anyone know how to solve this? Or is it not currently possible?

Example is in this code -->

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.ToolTipManager;


public class JTooltipFlickerTest extends JFrame {


JPanel panel;

static public void main (final String[] args) {
    new JTooltipFlickerTest ();
}

public JTooltipFlickerTest () {
    super ();
    //ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false); 
    //ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setReshowDelay(0); 

    setTitle (this.getClass().toString());
    setSize (1024, 768);

    this.getContentPane().setLayout (new BorderLayout());

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater (
        new Runnable () {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                panel = new JPanel ();

                final MouseAdapter ma = new MouseAdapter () {

                    public void mouseMoved (final MouseEvent e) { 
                        panel.setToolTipText ("x: "+e.getX()+", y: "+e.getY());
                    }
                };  
                panel.addMouseMotionListener(ma);

                //panel.setDoubleBuffered(true);
                //panel.createToolTip().setDoubleBuffered(true);

                JTooltipFlickerTest.this.getContentPane().add (panel, "Center");                
                JTooltipFlickerTest.this.setVisible (true);
            }
        }
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow, the `javax.swing.RepaintManager` class can help with the tool-tip repaint issue. The class that extends the `RepaintManager` below is taken from the example in **Chapter 11, Repaint Manager**: http://www.java.net/external?url=http://www.curious-creature.org/2007/07/22/repaint-manager-demos-chapter-11/

It is modified to repaint `JTooltipFlickerTest`'s contentpane...

Try to comment out `installRepaintManager()` call in the constructor and you will see the difference...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.RepaintManager;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JTooltipFlickerTest extends JFrame {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JPanel panel;

    static public void main (final String[] args) {
        new JTooltipFlickerTest ();
    }


    public JTooltipFlickerTest () {
        super ();
        panel = new JPanel ();          

        setTitle (this.getClass().toString());
        setSize (1024, 768);

        this.getContentPane().setLayout (new BorderLayout());

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater (
                new Runnable () {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        final MouseAdapter ma = new MouseAdapter () {

                            public void mouseMoved (final MouseEvent e) { 
                                panel.setToolTipText ("x: "+e.getX()+", y: "+e.getY());
                            }
                        };  
                        panel.addMouseMotionListener(ma);

                        panel.setDoubleBuffered(true);
                        panel.createToolTip().setDoubleBuffered(true);

                        JTooltipFlickerTest.this.getContentPane().add (panel, "Center");                
                        JTooltipFlickerTest.this.setVisible (true);
                    }
                }
        );

        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        installRepaintManager();

    }

    private void installRepaintManager() {
        ReflectionRepaintManager manager = new ReflectionRepaintManager();
        RepaintManager.setCurrentManager(manager);
    }

    private class ReflectionRepaintManager extends RepaintManager {
        public void addDirtyRegion(JComponent c, int x, int y, int w, int h) {

            int lastDeltaX = c.getX();
            int lastDeltaY = c.getY();

            Container parent = c.getParent();
            while (parent instanceof JComponent) {
                if (!parent.isVisible()) {
                    return;
                }

                if (parent instanceof JTooltipFlickerTest) {
                    x += lastDeltaX;
                    y += lastDeltaY;

                    int gap = getContentPane().getHeight() - h - y;
                    h += 2 * gap + h;

                    lastDeltaX = lastDeltaY = 0;

                    c = (JComponent) parent;
                }

                lastDeltaX += parent.getX();
                lastDeltaY += parent.getY();

                parent = parent.getParent();
            }

            super.addDirtyRegion(c, x, y, w, h);
        }
    }
}
```

**edited**

When `installRepaintManager()` is disabled, the whole tooltip flickers on both sides of the the edge boundary (it is the same effect as in OP's original code).

When `installRepaintManager()` is enabled, one part of the tooltip area doesn't flicker inside of the edge boundary. In contrast, the other part of it flickers outside of the edge boundary. But, the flicker is not so bad compared to when `installRepaintManager()` is disabled.

I know, it is a subtle difference which I guess it leaves nothing to be desired of. At least, the words in the tooltip area are a little bit legible when `installRepaintManager()` is enabled.

Even when the double-buffered codes are disabled, `installRepaintManager()` works as expected; that is, the heavyweight component is rapidly repainted to reduce the flicker.

```
//panel.setDoubleBuffered(true);
//panel.createToolTip().setDoubleBuffered(true);
```

Comment: mmm... I'm not seeing any difference. What I have discovered is that tooltips and popups are set to be not truly doublebuffered i.e. hardware double buffered - and the way classes are set up means this can't be change through subclassing etc

Comment: @mgraham: When `installRepaintManager()` is enabled, the part of the tooltip area that overlaps with the panel doesn't flicker; the other part flickers.  When `installRepaintManager()` is disabled, the whole tooltip flickers. It is a subtle difference which I guess it leaves nothing to be desired of. At least, the words in the tooltip area is a little bit legible when `installRepaintManager()` is enabled.

Comment: yeah, I can see that now. I can make a fake tooltip with an undecorated JFrame containing a JTooltip that I move all over the screen with negligible flicker, so it seems its particular to the HeavyWeightPopup class that the tooltip uses... suspicions on the true double buffering caveat...

It's worse for me as I use multi-line HTML tooltips so the flicker is really bad... + I want to use a translucent heavyweight window for the tooltip, so that makes the flicker occur even in the component.

I'd give you an upvote or whatever for trying but I'm not allowed by lack of previous posts...

Comment: @mgraham: I have tested it for a translucent heavyweight fake tooltip. The result? It still behaves exactly like what I have described. But, I could not achieve a satisfactory result if I want it to be over the top of any any window. I will update my post if I have the time... Don't worry: I don't really care about the voting system. What important is that we can learn and share our knowledge ;)

Comment: @mgraham: Sorry, it is the other way around..It works well for `setAlwaysOnTop(true)` through `PopupFactory`. But, it is a flicker fest when `setOpaque(false)`