# Java Graphics: Each time it repaints, i get a blackflash

Tags: java, graphics, draw

I'm pretty new to the java draw functions, but I have a sample histogram that I build. on button click, i have it rebuilding the histogram with random values. However, every time i hit the button to repaint, i get a black flash before it redraws. I remember hearing this was pretty common and the fix had something to do with buffering. Any advice?

Comment: What you're reminded of is called "double buffering" @glowcoder has a great answer. @camickr gives a good reference for custom painting.

Comment: You can also use install and use a class extended from `javax.swing.RepaintManager` to repaint all members of a component tree... `This class manages repaint requests, allowing the number of repaints to be minimized, for example by collapsing multiple requests into a single repaint for members of a component tree.` A sample usage can be found in my post on the issue with heavyweight flickering component http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500999/possible-to-stop-flickering-java-tooltip-in-heavyweight-mode/5503728#comment-6378805

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing you do when you draw is clear your canvas. The flash you see is the blank canvas as things get drawn. If you were to slow it down fast enough, you would see each thing appear on the screen, one at a time.

You can get around this by what's called double buffering.

You paint your screen to an off-screen image. Then you paint your image to the screen all at once.

Answer (score 2):

Swing is double buffered by default.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for working examples.

Comment: Swing being double-buffered or not, seen that Java does **not** perform vertical-sync you cannot get rid of all the tearing effects. Of course the OP wants to use double-buffering, but he may still have it's 'redraw' performed at the wrong time and end up with the dreaded sharding effect (all too common with Swing apps that do "animations") http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_tearing